# The website works fine with certificat HTTPS inside the virtual machine (VM) but not outside

Tags: apache, https, ssl-certificate, wamp

My website is installed on the VM (vm azure) with WAMP Apache server. I've installed the certificate, and it works fine on the VM using HTTPS. However, from outside, the site is inaccessible, it shows this site cannot be reached.
Before, when it was in HTTP, it was accessible from outside.

Here are the steps I took to install the certificate on Apache WAMP:

1. Copy your SSL certificate (.crt file) and your private key (.key file) to the directory.
2. Uncomment the modules:

```
   LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so 
   LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
   Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

3. Configure httpd-ssl.conf:

   (Listen 443) is enable

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "${SRVROOT}/logs/access.log"
….
SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/crt/certificat.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-dsa.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-ecc.crt"
….
.….
.….
SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/crt/certificat.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-dsa.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-ecc.key"
```

4. Configure vhost:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/site"
  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/site">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/site"
  <Directory "c:/wamp/www/site">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2/conf/crt/certificat.crt "
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2/conf/crt/certificat.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you configured Windows firewall to allow apache to provide TCP port 443 to the Internet?

Comment: Yes, port 443 is enabled.

Comment: Did you open port 443 for VM (in Azure)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov, yes it's open,  Is my configuration on apache is correct? Did I forget something?

Comment: @LAS, you need to add CA file with full chain of your SSL provider certificates

Comment: @LAS, check `SSLCACertificateFile`

Comment: @RomeoNinov Is the CA file essential for the website to be accessible from outside?

Comment: It is good practice to have it. Not sure how much clients depend on it. Do you have Azure Firewall enabled/configured?

Comment: Yes the Firewall is enabled on port 443